# access method 'system.window.dpiscale.get_pielperinchy() failed

Tags: visual-studio, windows-update

I am not able to run a visual studio 2022, even though Visal studio installer also not opening to have update or uninstall VS.
I am receiving following  Error
[image]

I tried searching  for same but I am not able to find a solution to fix the same. I am getting some
"system.window.dpiscale" Option